# Display nested lists in Codeigniter

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

I have the following tables in my database:

```
projects(id, name)
subprojects(id, project_id, name)
```

I would like to display the projects and theirs subprojects in nested lists. Here is an example:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Project</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Project</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Project</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Project</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I'm using CodeIgniter as framework, what is the best way to achieve the result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should do a select inside foreach the projects result array

```
$query = " select * from projects";
$query = $this->db->query($query);
$result = $query->result_array() ;
foreach($result as $key=>$value)
{
   $query = " select * from subprojects where project_id='".$value['id']."' ";
   $query = $this->db->query($query);
   $result[$key]['subproject'] = $query->result_array() ;
}
```

and inside the view

```
foreach($result as $row)
{
   echo " <li><a href='#'>".$row['name']."</a>";    
   if(isset($row['subproject']))
   {
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach($row['subproject'] as $sub)
    echo " <li><a href='#'>".$sub['name']."</a>";    
    echo "</ul>";
   }
   else
   {
    echo "</li>";
   }
}
```

Comment: I get error in foreach.{ Invalid argument supplied for foreach() }
can you show me the controller?

Comment: the above code will be in the model you should return the $result and in the controller send it to the view via $data['result']